# Help simplifying vector calculus

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I'm working on a problem and I have come to the following:
$$\nabla \cdot (\nabla \vec{u} + (\nabla\vec{u})^T)$$
$$ = \nabla \cdot \nabla\vec{u} + \nabla \cdot (\nabla\vec{u})^T$$
From knowing the solution of the problem, this is supposed to simplify to:
$$\nabla^2\vec{u}$$
But I can't see how this is done. I'm pretty sure I did the first step right?

Comment: Can you add further context? Express the goal of the exercise clearly and its premises

Comment: I don't think the context is necessary? It's a physics problem where I am deriving a known equation, I just don't see mathematically how it works out.

Comment: To clarify, I believe my misunderstanding relates to $\nabla^2\vec{u}$ being a tensor. By definition the Laplace operator is $\nabla^2 f = \nabla \cdot \nabla f$. But since u is a vector this turns it into a tensor and I'm just confused how it works out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(i,j)$-component of $\nabla \vec{u} + (\nabla \vec{u})^T$ is $$\partial_j u_i + \partial_i u_j$$ So the $j$th entry of $\nabla\cdot (\nabla \vec{u} + (\nabla \vec{u})^T)$ is (in Einstein convention) $$\partial_i(\partial_j u_i + \partial_i u_j) = \partial_j(\partial_i u_i) + \partial_i\partial_i u_j$$ The latter is the $j$th entry of $\nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec{u}) +  \nabla^2\vec{u}$, so $$\nabla\cdot (\nabla\vec{u} + (\nabla \vec{u})^T) = \nabla(\nabla\cdot \vec{u}) + \nabla^2\vec{u}$$ You need to have $\nabla \cdot \vec{u} = 0$ in order to simplify to $\nabla^2\vec{u}$. This will hold true, e.g., when $\vec{u}$ is the fluid velocity field of an incompressible flow.

Comment: Ah! Thank you so much!!